# variable substitution - each value becomes an argument

Tags: tcl

When a variable is substituted and the value is a list, is it possible that each value of the list is regarded as one argument?

Here is an example code:

```
set a "-nonewline hi"
puts $a
```

What I really want is after the substitution, the puts command becomes `puts -nonewline hi` instead of `puts "-nonewline hi"`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17158):

```
puts {*}$a
```

In versions prior to 8.5, you would have to use `eval`:

```
eval puts $a
```